# Web API [FromUri] Get Method Mapping

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I could very well be setting this up wrong. But my get method in my web api controller.

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{productId:guid}", Name = nameof(GetProduct))]
    [ResponseType(typeof(Product))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetProduct([FromUri]GetProductRequest request)
```

inside the request i have the Guid ProductId

```
public class GetProductRequest 
{
    public const string ProductIdRequired = nameof(ProductId) + " cannot be empty";

    [Required(ErrorMessage = ProductIdRequired)]
    public Guid ProductId { get; set; }
}
```

I expected the request url to look something like localhost/v1/product/123

but it is localhost/v1/product/{ProductId}?productId=123&request.productId=123'

if i drop the Route {productId:guid}
i get localhos/v1/product?request.productId=123' which is also strange. Not sure why it wants request.productId in the url.

Comment: you'll need to decorate the property with `[FromRoute]`

Comment: @DanielA.White You can use `[FromRoute]` only in asp.net core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two places where you're instructing MVC to parse an input value: The `[Route]` attribute, plus the `[FromUri]` attribute on the controller method parameter.

Try this:

1. Drop the `[FromUri]` from the controller method.
2. Change the controller parameter to simply be `Guid productId`, which matches the value of your attribute route configuration `[Route({productId:guid})]`.

You should then see it respond to requests at: `localhost/v1/product/{productId}`